# Magento Sample data Installation: Table already exists

Tags: magento, sample-data

I am trying to install Magento's sample data for a few days now and have tried numerous things but nothing seems to work.

I am using easyphp 5.3.3.1 on windows 7.

I downloaded the sample data files and ran the SQL to create tables for the sample data. After that I ran the Magento installation and right after it asks for database information I get the following error

```
Zend_Db_Statement_Exception Object
(
    [_previous:Zend_Exception:private] => 
    [message:protected] => SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'admin_assert' already exists
[string:Exception:private] => 
    [code:protected] => 42
    [file:protected] => I:\EasyPHP-5.3.3.1\www\magento\magento\lib\Zend\Db\Statement\Pdo.php
    [line:protected] => 234
    [trace:Exception:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [file] => I:\EasyPHP-5.3.3.1\www\magento\magento\lib\Varien\Db\Statement\Pdo\Mysql.php
                    [line] => 110
                    [function] => _execute
                    [class] => Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [file] => I:\EasyPHP-5.3.3.1\www\magento\magento\lib\Zend\Db\Statement.php
                    [line] => 300
                    [function] => _execute
                    [class] => Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (.......
```

and so on....

It just doesn't complete the installation. What could be causing this error?

Comment: Windows is not a supported Platform for Magento.
Can you install a Linux Virtual Machine and try it there?

Comment: @Alex that is simply not true. I am running Windows 7 on my dev machine with several Magento sites on it.

Comment: What version of Magento are you using? Did you completely clear the database before doing the last sample import?

Comment: i am using the latest version of magento. Yes the database was clear. @Alex magento says it's compatible with windows.

Comment: When i installed the sample data I got this warning:

Error
SQL query: 

SELECT  `comment` 
FROM  `phpmyadmin`.`pma_column_info` 
WHERE db_name =  'magento'
AND table_name =  ''
AND column_name =  '(db_comment)'

MySQL said: 

#1100 - Table 'pma_column_info' was not locked with LOCK TABLES

Comment: Can you try to install the sample data in the mysql console client instead of phpmyadmin - but it should work with phpmyadmin, too. Anyways, the error you describe is phpmyadmin related.

Comment: @djdy It might run - but it is not officially supported "Supported Operating Systems:
Linux x86, x86-64" http://www.magentocommerce.com/system-requirements

Comment: your problem is clearly phpMyAdmin related, try the console or the mysql Workbench

Answer (score 0):

You are aware that you are supposed to install the sample data BEFORE you install Magento? It looks like you are trying to install the data when Magento has already created some tables..

1) Empty the database.

2) Import the data into the database.

3) Install a fresh Magento

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/installing-the-sample-data-for-magento

Comment: Yes I am aware of that. I installed the data before installing magento. I think it was some windows related issue as it ran fine on linux server/